# Цвета темы AppCompat

Tags: android, android-themes, android-appcompat

В проекте есть файл *res\values\colors.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="dark_grey">#424242</color>
    <color name="medium_grey">#9E9E9E</color>
    <color name="button_grey">#757575</color>
</resources>
```

и файл *res\values\styles.xml*:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"></style>
</resources>
```

И в *AndroidManifest.xml*:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

И при запуске приложения цвет Status Bar — `dark_grey` и цвет заголовка приложения (App Bar) определяется как `button_grey`.
Каким образом определяется цвет заголовка приложения (App Bar) и цвет Status Bar, если в файле *styles.xml* нет определения цветов?

Comment: Из дефолтной темы - primary разные

Comment: @pavlofff, а можно, пожалуйста, подробнее?.. Имелось в виду, что цвета берутся не из файла colors.xml, а из дефолтной темы Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar?

Comment: Да, если в приложении атрибуты стилей не переопределены они берутся из темы, заданной для приложения

Comment: @pavlofff, а где в sdk можно найти эту тему?

Comment: @pavlofff, большое cпасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в собственной теме приложения какие-то параметры цвета, размера и проч. стилизации не указаны, то они берутся из базовой темы системы, а в случае библиотеки AppCompat, из ее стилей. Сами параметры определяются тем, от какой темы отнаследована ваша тема приложения, например:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Здесь, в случае если в текущем файле не указано иное, все цвета, размеры виджетов и пр. будут браться из темы библиотеки AppCompat - светлая с темным экшенбаром.

Отредактировать цвета темы приложения и указать еще некоторые ее основные параметры удобнее всего через инструмент Android Studio - Theme Editor (Tools -> Android -> Theme Editor):

[image: screen]

Инструмент позволяет выбрать основу темы (светлая темная и тд), от какой базовой темы наследоваться, а так же изменить некоторые ее параметры.  Здесь же можно увидеть, как будут выглядеть виджеты и протестировать их вид на различных API (из тех, что установлены в SDK Manager).

Полный файл стилей тем библиотеки AppCompat можно получить,  переключив отображение дерева проекта с *Android* на *Project* и там в разделе *External Libraries* она лежит в ресурсах папки AppCompat (файл res/values/values.xml):

[image: screen2]

Здесь можно найти все атрибуты стилей, которые можно затем переопределить в своей теме. Стоит заметить, что файл очень не удобен для чтения и работы вообще и если не знаешь, где примерно искать, можно потратить достаточное количество времени.